# PHP generate list from sqlite database

Tags: php, arrays, list, sqlite

I'm looking to generate a list with php from a Sqlite-database.
The list is supposed to be used in a lottery, the tickets column are the number of tickets, and the list needs to output the user x number of times based on that (see example below)

I can't wrap my head around this, I have no problems getting an array, but how do I tackle that array and examine that to get to the end goal?

```
|user |tickets|
---------------
|user1| 5     |
|user2| 2     |
|user3| 1     |
```

Expected results

```
user1
user1
user1
user1
user1
user2
user2
user3
```

Comment: Let's suppose you got the results from a SQLite SQL query as per your first sample above. From that, you'd read each row (usually in a `while` loop, so it runs until there are no more rows to read), and then within the loop which reads the rows, you make a `for` loop which loops `tickets` number of times and echoes the `user` value.

Comment: Cheers, got me a bit on the way, but in the for-loop I guess I need to use count, and just using count straight up returns user and tickets, how do I go about and using tickets? I used something like this but its no good -  {
  for ($i = 0; $i > count($tickets['tickets']);$i++);
   echo $tickets['user']."\n";
 }

Comment: Please forgive formatting, I have no clue how to format in comments :)

Comment: You cam [edit] your question when you have code to show, so don't worry about formatting in the comments :-)

Comment: Anyway that looks nearly right but `>` should probably be `<` in the loop definition!

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, int given" is what I get with ['tickets']

Comment: Drop the count - `for ($i = 0; $i < $tickets['tickets'];$i++)` ...it's already a number. count() is for when you've got a list or array and you need to know how many items are in it. (The error is telling you that you tried to pass an int (I.e. whole number) into the count function, but, per what I've just said, you'd need to pass in an array. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: Ok, dropping count gets rid of the error, but it only echoes users once (user1, user2, user3) and not the amount of times as tickets

Comment: That would apparently be because you made the popular newbie mistake of putting a semicolon right after your loop, according to that code snippet from the second comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose you got the results from a SQLite SQL query as per your first sample above. From that, you'd read each row (usually in a `while` loop, so it runs until there are no more rows to read).

Then within the loop which reads the rows, you make a `for` loop which loops `tickets` number of times and echoes the `user` value - something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $tickets['tickets']; $i++)
{
  echo $tickets['user']."\n";
}
```